# Does 'hg add' ignore '.hgignore'?

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

I am new to Mercurial, having used Git previously. I believe I am using Mercurial incorrectly.

To ignore, e.g. `.DS_Store`, with git, one would add `.DS_Store` to `.gitignore`. Then if one did `git add -A`, git still wouldn't track `.DS_Store`.

However, after adding `.DS_Store` to `.hgignore`, and then doing `hg forget .DS_Store`, `hg add` adds `.DS_Store` back, as can be confirmed via `hg status`. The same problem even happens after doing `hg forget "set:hgignore()"`.

**Question:** What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This was a stupid question, since I just figured out the answer. Since I couldn't find the answer on Google or StackOverflow, I will post it here. If this question is a duplicate, please just delete it (without insulting me).

Anyway the answer is that I hadn't done `hg commit` yet. After doing `hg forget .DS_Store` and then a `hg commit`, `hg add` no longer re-adds `.DS_Store`, since it is located in `.hgignore`.

Comment: To clarify, what was it that you committed that made the difference?

Comment: @DaveInCaz Anything not including the `.DS_Store`'s (i.e. after checking `hg status --all` to ensure that none were being tracked anymore), the commit works. After the commit, `hg add` no longer adds back the `.DS_Store`'s.